# WPF paragraph keydown not firing

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, keydown, paragraph

I have added KeyDown, PreviewKeyDown event (and some more) to a programmatically created Paragraph:

```
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        Run r = new Run("new Text here");
        p.Inlines.Add(r);
        p.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(p_KeyDown);
        p.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(p_PreviewKeyDown);
        p.PreviewTextInput += new TextCompositionEventHandler(p_PreviewTextInput);
        p.TextInput += new TextCompositionEventHandler(p_TextInput);
        myrtb.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
```

But none of them is firing when I change the text ("new Text here") in the RichTextBox. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?
Many thanks!

Comment: Why not handle the Rich Textbox KeyDown?

Comment: It has different reasons. After receiving the event I have rearrange the blocks in the RichTextBox document in some way. So after that I don't know which block (paragraph) was clicked. If I could receive the event for the paragraph I wouldn't have these problems. Microsoft provides the KeyDown event for blocks. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell, the RichTextBox does not route KeyDown events to the current selected Block/Paragraph, therefore you will have to handle the RTB events, and get the current Paragraph by using the current CaretPosition.

Comment: Do you know why Microsoft provides the KeyDown event for block i.e. paragraphs? It doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: I wanted to achieve similar thing for the project I am doing. Looks like these events fire, when we set the IsDocumentEnabled property and add some UI controls(Like textbox) to FlowDocument and inside UI gets keydowns.